# Generating all logic propositions

Tags: logic, algorithms, propositional-calculus

I'm looking for a way of generating all logic propositions (propositional calculus) in an "algorithmic" way. The equivalence is symbolic, so $\neg\neg a \neq a$ and $\neg a \lor b \neq a \implies b$, for example (I think that makes things easier), but $a \land b = b \land c$ (variables are equivalent)

I'm using Haskell for this, in case anyone would like to give a techy solution. You can use expressions to build new expressions and match them against proposition "templates" (e.g. $(a \lor b) \land c \in a \land b$).

Any ideas on how to approach the problem with the given conditions? Any kind of help will be greatly appreciaded.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course you can't generate ALL propositions since there are $\infty$ many.  I think a good approach is to define the grammar of your calculus and then generate all combinations of symbols of length 1, 2. 3, ... and in each case verify that a sequence of symbols is a valid proposition using your grammar.

Comment: @Jedediyah: I thin the OP is looking to _enumerate_ the propositions, not to finish generating them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Isn't that essentially the same procedure though?  It sounds like he is generating expressions and trying to validate them.  I think verifying against a grammar is far more robust than checking against a set of templates, since that would require he also generate all possible templates to check against.

Comment: @Jedediyah: All I was pointing out is that your first sentence doesn't apply to _enumerating_ the propositions. The rest looks like a reasonable suggestion -- though in a programming context one would probably want to enumerate trees rather than strings. The more interesting problem is to avoid generating terms that are renamings of each other more than once, in a reasonably slick way.

Comment: @Jedediyah well, as Henning Makholm pointed it's obvious I'm not trying to finish doing so, I'm just looking for an enumeration. I've thought about the "text-based" approach but I don't really like it and I already know how to do it. This is different, since I know everything I can generate is a valid expression, but I don't know how to generate them all.

Comment: @cronos2 Got it.  The issue is that it's very difficult to know if you've generated all of the propositions possible without trying everything by brute force and validating each statement.

Comment: The language of all propositional formulae is context free. Therefore you may want to take it a step further and [enumerate context free languages](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259674303_Enumerating_algebraic_expressions_generated_by_context-free_grammars).

Comment: @Jedediyah:  lazy functional programming languages like Haskell let you work with infinite lists.

Comment: @Stefan nice contribution, but in the paper they only provide a way to _count_ words of length $l$ in a given language, not a way to "easily" _enumerate_ them

Comment: @cronos2 Sorry, that wasn't the link I wanted to provide and I seem to be unable to recall the paper I was thinking of. However, one way to enumerate a context free language is the following: Build a parser for your grammar, generate all possible strings in your language and output only those that the parser accepts. You may want to have a look at the [Wikipedia article for Earley's parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) or [Earley's Thesis](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/anon/usr/ftp/scan/CMU-CS-68-earley.pdf).